# Dataframe: joining rows in based on a Month column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Within one dataframe, trying to concatenate rows which have the same price, customer etc. Only variable that's changing is Month.

Would the best solution be to split the dataframe into 2 ? and then use a merge function?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please check [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and edit your question.

Comment: You might want to have a loot at [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html).